# IOS charts with different X,Y values in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-charts

I had an iPhone application in which i have to calculate the values for x axis and y axis with some intervals as xaxis array and Yaxis array
I had fixed values.

> Then i need to draw 3 line graph with their on x values and Y
>   values.then i need to plot scatter points on that graph itself with
>   different (x,y) coordinates.
>
> I am using IOs charts library.But when giving different x values to
>   the line graph the X axis values are also changing, I am trying in
>   this way

```
`  chartview.descriptionText = @"";
    chartview.noDataTextDescription = @"You need to provide data for the chart.";

    chartview.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = NO;
    chartview.drawBarShadowEnabled = NO;
    chartview.highlightFullBarEnabled = NO;
    chartview.rightAxis.enabled=NO;


    chartview.drawOrder = @[@(CombinedChartDrawOrderLine),
                            @(CombinedChartDrawOrderScatter),
                            ];

    ChartLegend *l = chartview.legend;
    l.enabled = false;
    //chartview.xAxisRenderer

    ChartYAxis *leftAxis = chartview.leftAxis;
    leftAxis.axisLineWidth=2.0f;

    leftAxis.axisLineColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
    leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = YES;
    leftAxis.gridColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    leftAxis.gridLineDashLengths = @[@5.f, @5.f];
    NSLog(@"%@",yaxispoints);
    NSLog(@"%f",[[yaxispoints firstObject] floatValue]);
      NSLog(@"%f",[[yaxispoints lastObject] floatValue]);
    leftAxis.axisMinimum = [[yaxispoints firstObject] floatValue]; // this replaces startAtZero = YES
    leftAxis.axisMaximum = [[yaxispoints lastObject] floatValue];

    leftAxis.labelCount = [yaxispoints count];
    leftAxis.spaceTop = 40.0;
    leftAxis.labelTextColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    ChartXAxis *xAxis = chartview.xAxis;
    [xAxis setDrawAxisLineEnabled:YES];
    xAxis.axisLineWidth=2.0f;
    xAxis.granularityEnabled=YES;

    xAxis.axisLineColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
    xAxis.labelPosition = XAxisLabelPositionBottom;
    xAxis.axisMinimum = [[months firstObject] floatValue]; // this replaces startAtZero = YES
    xAxis.axisMaximum = [[months lastObject] floatValue];
    xAxis.labelCount = [months count];

    xAxis.forceLabelsEnabled=YES;
    xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = YES;
    xAxis.gridColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    xAxis.gridLineDashLengths = @[@5.f, @5.f];
    xAxis.valueFormatter = self;
    xAxis.labelTextColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [self updateChartData];
    [chartview animateWithXAxisDuration:1.5 yAxisDuration:1.5];`


  - (void)updateChartData
{


    [self setChartData];

}

- (void)setChartData
{
    CombinedChartData *data = [[CombinedChartData alloc] init];
    data.lineData = [self generateLineData];

   data.scatterData = [self generateScatterData];
   chartview.xAxis.axisMaximum = data.xMax + 5.0;

    chartview.data = data;

}

- (LineChartData *)generateLineData
{
    LineChartData *d = [[LineChartData alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSArray *scxaxis = @[@"55.987", @"75.976", @"85.976"
                          ];
  NSArray *scyaxis = @[@"85.987", @"25.976", @"95.976"
                          ];

    for (int index = 0; index < [scxaxis count]; index++)
    {
        [entries addObject:[[ChartDataEntry alloc] initWithX:[[scxaxis objectAtIndex:index] doubleValue] y:[[scyaxis objectAtIndex:index] doubleValue]]];
    }

    LineChartDataSet *set = [[LineChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:entries label:@"Line DataSet"];
    [set setColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    set.lineWidth = 3.0;
   // [set setCircleColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    //set.circleRadius = 0.0;
   // set.circleHoleRadius = 0.0;
    set .drawCirclesEnabled=NO;
    set.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    set.mode = LineChartModeLinear;
    set.drawValuesEnabled = NO;

    set.valueFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f];
    set.valueTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    set.axisDependency = AxisDependencyLeft;

    [d addDataSet:set];

    return d;
}
```

I am trying like this,But when giving different x values to each data set in line graph the x axis is completely going wrong according to it. i want the x axis to be fetched from different array and x,y points of line graph to be from different array, Can anybody help me on achieving this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is

```
chartview.xAxis.axisMaximum = data.xMax + 5.0;
```

Cause you are using `CombinedChartData`,if the  you should call `calcMinMax()` at first.

And accord to your code ,the x axis should be in [0,90.976].What your graph shows?